# transform on multiple columns to interpolate/copy missing values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I'm trying to fill out missing values in a pandas dataframe by interpolating or copying the last-known value within a group (identified by `trip`). My data looks like this:

```
    brake   speed   trip
0   0.0     NaN     1
1   1.0     NaN     1
2   NaN     1.264   1
3   NaN     0.000   1
4   0.0     NaN     1
5   NaN     1.264   1
6   NaN     6.704   1
7   1.0     NaN     1
8   0.0     NaN     1
9   NaN     11.746  2
10  1.0     NaN     2
11  0.0     NaN     2
12  NaN     16.961  3
13  1.0     NaN     3
14  NaN     11.832  3
15  0.0     NaN     3
16  NaN     17.082  3
17  NaN     22.435  3
18  NaN     28.707  3
19  NaN     34.216  3
```

I have found [Pandas interpolate within a groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby) but I need `brake` to simply be copied from the last-known, yet `speed` to be interpolated (my actual dataset has 12 columns that each need such treatment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply separate methods to each column. For example:

```
# interpolate speed
df['speed'] = df.groupby('trip').speed.transform(lambda x: x.interpolate())
# fill brake with last known value 
df['brake'] = df.groupby('trip').brake.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))

>>> df
    brake    speed  trip
0     0.0      NaN     1
1     1.0      NaN     1
2     1.0   1.2640     1
3     1.0   0.0000     1
4     0.0   0.6320     1
5     0.0   1.2640     1
6     0.0   6.7040     1
7     1.0   6.7040     1
8     0.0   6.7040     1
9     NaN  11.7460     2
10    1.0  11.7460     2
11    0.0  11.7460     2
12    NaN  16.9610     3
13    1.0  14.3965     3
14    1.0  11.8320     3
15    0.0  14.4570     3
16    0.0  17.0820     3
17    0.0  22.4350     3
18    0.0  28.7070     3
19    0.0  34.2160     3
```

Note that this means you remain with some `NaN` in brake, because there was no "last known value" for the first row of a trip, and some `NaNs` in speed when the first few rows were `NaN`. You can replace these as you see fit with [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: That's actually fine. I keep forgetting that I can do stuff with individual columns. Is this the fastest way to go about this? I have about 6 million rows; this solution is doable for me at a minute and a half, but if there's a faster way I'm very much interested.