# Python fastest group interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, pandas-groupby

In Python I have data that looks like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'currency':['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD'], 
                   'tenor':[1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 2, 5, 10],
                   'value':[10, 20, np.nan, 100, 1, 2, 3, np.nan]})
```

I want to group by currency and linearly interpolate NaNs based on tenor, i.e. I want to achieve

```
data.index = data['tenor']
data['value'] = data.groupby('currency')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('values'))
```

The issue is that interpolate in pandas is very slow. I have several thousands  groups within groupby and the entire dataframe has 10 million rows.

Is there a fast way to do interpolation over groups?
I tried numpy

```
result = data.groupby('currency')[['tenor', 'value']].apply(lambda x: list(fun(x['tenor'].values, x['value'].values)))
```

where

```
def fun(x, y):
    isNaN = np.isnan(y)
    return np.interp(x, x[~isNaN], y[~isNaN])
```

which is faster but not so much.

Can you recommend the fastest within-group interpolation in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby

Comment: I've seen this post already. My numpy implementation is faster than any of the proposed methods, yet still not fast enough. Any better ideas?

Comment: Writing it in c/c++ ;) No i have always the same problem. Did you check with line_profiler where the problem is coming from. You also can use dask - https://dask.org/

Comment: Can we assume that `data['tenor']` is sorted within each group?

Comment: @Michael yes, sorted