# replace nans with max value plus 1 incrementally

Tags: python

I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

I want to fill the NaNs by continuing from the max value for that year (i.e. increase incrementally based on the max value for each year).

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The only way I know how to apply something like this to each year separately is by creating separate data frames for each year in a for loop, then appending them back together.

```
#data
d = {'year': {0: 2016,
  1: 2016,
  2: 2016,
  3: 2016,
  4: 2017,
  5: 2017,
  6: 2017,
  7: 2017,
  8: 2018,
  9: 2018,
  10: 2018},
 'id': {0: 1015.0,
  1: 1016.0,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 1035.0,
  5: 1036.0,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 1005.0,
  9: nan,
  10: nan}}

# list of years
years = [2016,2017,2018]

# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# create list that I will append data frames too
l = []

for x in years:
    # create a dataframe for each year
    df1 = df[df['year']==x].copy()
    # fill nans with max value plus 1
    df1['id'] = df1['id'].fillna(lambda x: x['id'].max() + 1)
    # add dataframe to list
    l.append(df1)
# concat list of dataframes
final = pd.concat(l)
```

This replaces the nans with the following text:

function  at 0x000002201F43CB70

I also tried using this in my for loop:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].apply(lambda x: x['id'].fillna(x['id'].max() +1))
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: df.interpolate might help ... just haven't figure out how to use it grouped by the year yet

Comment: @Will You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37057425/8673150) to combine with df.interpolate with group by.  But I am not sure how to achieve max value+1 with interpolate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `df.iterrows()` to go through rows and `df.loc[]` to set missing 'id' values:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['id'] > 0 : continue
    df.loc[index,"id"] = df[df['year']==row['year']]['id'].max() +1
```

**EDIT**

A nicer way to check if row['id'] is not null would be:

```
    if pd.notnull(row['id']): ...
```

Comment: This adds 1 to every row. Even the existing values. I won't downvote because you are close!

Comment: There si an if statement to avoid that :)

Comment: I ran your code on his data and that is what returned :P.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I hardly manage to handle conditions with np.nan. Replaced it with a null value

Comment: So as long as the df is sorted by year this should work