# Groupby fill missing values in dataframe based on average of previous values available and next value available

Tags: python, sql, machine-learning, pyspark, missing-data

I have data frame which has some groups and I want to fill the missing values based on last previous available and next value available average of score column i.e. (previous value+next value)/2.

I want to group by state,school,class,subject and then fill value.

If the first value not available in score column then fill the value with value which is available next or
If the last value not available then fill the value with value which is available previously
for each group this needs to be followed.

It is data imputation complex problem. I searched online and found pandas has some functionality i.e.
pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill but dont know how to use in this case.

I am thinking to solve in  python,pyspark,SQL !

My data frame looks like this

[image: Missing values]

[image: Data Imputation]

Comment: Shouldnt the math score be 46 for all of the records in Texas Crescent school?

Comment: Nope,you are missing the class group !!

Comment: do you want to fill in that way only? what about interpolate them after grouping them?

Comment: That would solve my problem if I can group and interpolate. The problem I am facing is how to group by and fill information @Pygirl

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby

Comment: Nope this wont solve the problem> I need to fill the values in the above manner only.grouping and filling doesnt let me create new column. I was thinking to create two columns by perform same grouping and different logic. Then merge the two to create final df

Comment: I know of a way to solve this in sql, but not sure if that is what you need here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful -

### Load the test data

```scala
df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----+-----+
      * |class|score|
      * +-----+-----+
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |46   |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |35   |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |46   |
      * |A    |null |
      * |A    |null |
      * |B    |78   |
      * |B    |null |
      * |B    |null |
      * |B    |null |
      * |B    |null |
      * |B    |null |
      * |B    |56   |
      * |B    |null |
      * +-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- class: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Impute Null values from score columns(check new_score column)

```scala
    val w1 = Window.partitionBy("class").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    val w2 = Window.partitionBy("class").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df2.withColumn("previous", last("score", ignoreNulls = true).over(w1))
      .withColumn("next", first("score", ignoreNulls = true).over(w2))
      .withColumn("new_score", (coalesce($"previous", $"next") + coalesce($"next", $"previous")) / 2)
      .drop("next", "previous")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+-----+---------+
      * |class|score|new_score|
      * +-----+-----+---------+
      * |A    |null |46.0     |
      * |A    |46   |46.0     |
      * |A    |null |40.5     |
      * |A    |null |40.5     |
      * |A    |35   |35.0     |
      * |A    |null |40.5     |
      * |A    |null |40.5     |
      * |A    |null |40.5     |
      * |A    |46   |46.0     |
      * |A    |null |46.0     |
      * |A    |null |46.0     |
      * |B    |78   |78.0     |
      * |B    |null |67.0     |
      * |B    |null |67.0     |
      * |B    |null |67.0     |
      * |B    |null |67.0     |
      * |B    |null |67.0     |
      * |B    |56   |56.0     |
      * |B    |null |56.0     |
      * +-----+-----+---------+
      */
```

Comment: Get the last available value for each row as previous ignoring nulls. Similarly get the next value present  and then compute the the average `previous + next/2`

Comment: Thanks,  I haven't used  $ in my pyspark code, wanted to confirm if this is pyspark or scala code ?

Comment: This is scala, but can be implemented the same in pyspark with minimal change. Replace $".." with F.col(...)

Comment: df.withColumn("previous", last("score", ignoreNulls = true).over(w1)).withColumn("next", first("score", ignoreNulls = true).over(w2)).withColumn("new_score", (coalesce(F.col("previous"), F.col("next") + coalesce(F.col("next"), F.col("previous")) / 2))).drop("next", "previous").show(false)

Comment: I already accepted and up voted the answer. Found it useful ! However I might need to change the above code to achieve desired result

Comment: This is how ok one should accept an answer- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/767994

Comment: Thanks for telling me that I didnt knew this earlier.I did it. Can upvote the question also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218660/discussion-between-code-run-and-someshwar-kale).