# Fill in row missing values with previous and next non missing values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I know you can forward/backward fill in missing values with next non-missing values with last function combined with a window function.

But I have a data looks like:

```
Area,Date,Population
A, 1/1/2000, 10000
A, 2/1/2000, 
A, 3/1/2000, 
A, 4/1/2000, 10030
A, 5/1/2000,
```

In this example, for May population, I like to fill in 10030 which is easy. But for Feb and Mar, I would like to fill in value is mean of 10000 and 10030, not 10000 or 10030.

Do you know how to implement this?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groupby fill missing values in dataframe based on average of previous values available and next value available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095958/groupby-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-based-on-average-of-previous-values-ava)

Answer (score 1):

Get the `next` and `previous` value and compute the mean as below-

```scala
df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+--------+----------+
      * |Area|Date    |Population|
      * +----+--------+----------+
      * |A   |1/1/2000|10000     |
      * |A   |2/1/2000|null      |
      * |A   |3/1/2000|null      |
      * |A   |4/1/2000|10030     |
      * |A   |5/1/2000|null      |
      * +----+--------+----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Area: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Population: integer (nullable = true)
      */

    val w1 = Window.partitionBy("Area").orderBy("Date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    val w2 = Window.partitionBy("Area").orderBy("Date").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df2.withColumn("previous", last("Population", ignoreNulls = true).over(w1))
      .withColumn("next", first("Population", ignoreNulls = true).over(w2))
      .withColumn("new_Population", (coalesce($"previous", $"next") + coalesce($"next", $"previous")) / 2)
      .drop("next", "previous")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+--------+----------+--------------+
      * |Area|Date    |Population|new_Population|
      * +----+--------+----------+--------------+
      * |A   |1/1/2000|10000     |10000.0       |
      * |A   |2/1/2000|null      |10015.0       |
      * |A   |3/1/2000|null      |10015.0       |
      * |A   |4/1/2000|10030     |10030.0       |
      * |A   |5/1/2000|null      |10030.0       |
      * +----+--------+----------+--------------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try.

`w1` and `w2` are used to partition the window and `w3` and `w4` are used to fill the preceding and following values. After that, you can give the condition to calculate how fill the `Population`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('Area').orderBy('Date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
w2 = Window.partitionBy('Area').orderBy('Date').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
w3 = Window.partitionBy('Area', 'partition1').orderBy('Date')
w4 = Window.partitionBy('Area', 'partition2').orderBy(f.desc('Date'))

df.withColumn('check', f.col('Population').isNotNull().cast('int')) \
  .withColumn('partition1', f.sum('check').over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('partition2', f.sum('check').over(w2)) \
  .withColumn('first', f.first('Population').over(w3)) \
  .withColumn('last',  f.first('Population').over(w4)) \
  .withColumn('fill', f.when(f.col('first').isNotNull() & f.col('last').isNotNull(), (f.col('first') + f.col('last')) / 2).otherwise(f.coalesce('first', 'last'))) \
  .withColumn('Population', f.coalesce('Population', 'fill')) \
  .orderBy('Date') \
  .select(*df.columns).show(10, False)

+----+--------+----------+
|Area|Date    |Population|
+----+--------+----------+
|A   |1/1/2000|10000.0   |
|A   |2/1/2000|10015.0   |
|A   |3/1/2000|10015.0   |
|A   |4/1/2000|10030.0   |
|A   |5/1/2000|10030.0   |
+----+--------+----------+
```