# Resample a dataframe, interpolate NaNs and return a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe `df` that contains data in periods of 3 hours:

```
index              , values
2003-01-01 00:00:00, 2.0    
2003-01-01 03:00:00, 1.8    
2003-01-01 06:00:00, 1.4    
2003-01-01 09:00:00, 1.1
....
```

I want to resample the data to every hour and interpolate the missing values in between linearly. I can achieve something similar, filling the missing values with `.bfill()`, and it looks like this:

```
df2 = df.resample('H').bfill()
```

I tried to alter this to achive my task as follows:

```
df2 = df.resample('H')
df2.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

But `df2 = df.resample('H')` in contrast to `df2 = df.resample('H').bfill()` doesn't return a dataframe object, but a `pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler object`.

Do you know how I can do the resampling and interpolation? Do you have some other work around? Tnx

Comment: From the docs: _resample() is a time-based groupby, followed by a reduction method on each of its groups. See some cookbook examples for some advanced strategies_. With this in mind, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby) answer might help you

Comment: @gionni Thanks, this helped! I actually found out from that I can just append my approach with `.interpolate()` and it would do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that I could just append my initial approach with `.interpolate()` and it would work:

```
df2 = df.resample('H').interpolate()
df2.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0, inplace=True)
```