# Pandas interpolate within a groupby for one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, interpolation

Similar to this question [Pandas interpolate within a groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby) but the answer to that question does the interpolate() for all columns. If I only want to limit the interpolate() to one column how do I do that?

Input

```
    filename    val1    val2
t                   
1   file1.csv   5       10
2   file1.csv   NaN     NaN
3   file1.csv   15      20
6   file2.csv   NaN     NaN
7   file2.csv   10      20
8   file2.csv   12      15
```

Expected Output

```
    filename    val1    val2
t                   
1   file1.csv   5       10
2   file1.csv   NaN     15
3   file1.csv   15      20
6   file2.csv   NaN     NaN
7   file2.csv   10      20
8   file2.csv   12      15
```

This attempt only returns val2 column but not the rest of the columns.

```
df = df.groupby('filename').apply(lambda group: group['val2'].interpolate(method='index'))
```

Comment: If it only returns `val2` column... as expected... then only push the results to the `val2` column... `df['val2'] = df.groupby(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct approach:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard() # clipboard contains OP sample data
# interpolate only on col "val2"
df["val2_interpolated"] = df[["filename","val2"]].groupby('filename')
.apply(lambda x:x) # WTF
.interpolate(method='linear')["val2"]
```

returns:

```
    filename  val1  val2  val2_interpolated
t
1  file1.csv   5.0  10.0               10.0
2  file1.csv   NaN   NaN               15.0
3  file1.csv  15.0  20.0               20.0
6  file2.csv   NaN   NaN               20.0
7  file2.csv  10.0  20.0               20.0
8  file2.csv  12.0  15.0               15.0
```

Comment: `groupby` has an `ignore_index` keyword, that'd be better than using `reset_index` after the fact~

Comment: perfect! exatcly what i was looking for, and yes, even as a newbie at pandas, that lambda x:x was a WTF moment!