# Pandas interpolate within groupby on certain column for a specific input value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, interpolation

This is very similar to these two topics:
[Follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550482/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby-for-one-column)
[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057187/pandas-interpolate-within-a-groupby)

I would need to interpolate not on all columns nor on a single column but on a set of columns (for instance two). Furthermore I would need to interpolate on a value which is most of the time missing from the reference column used for the interpolation. A small example will clarify:

Original dataframe:

```
    input_date    pivot_column    val1    val2
t
1   2023/11/02    16              3300    37
2   2023/11/02    14              3100    33
3   2023/11/02    10              3000    32.7
4   2023/11/03    17.5            3350    36.11
5   2023/11/03    15.75           3200    33.3
6   2023/11/03    14.25           3000    31.3
```

For each unique value in the column input_date, I would like to compute the interpolated values for columns val1 and val2 based on an hypothetical value of 15 from column pivot_column so something like

```
     input_date    pivot_column    val1    val2
t
1    2023/11/02    15              3200    35
2    2023/11/03    15              3100    32.3
```

I can use the solution from the follow-up question thread, ie

```
df["val2_interpolated"] = df[["filename","val2"]].groupby('filename')
.apply(lambda x:x) # WTF
.interpolate(method='linear')["val2"]
```

but how can I force the interpolation to be done around a pivot/input value of 15 for instance? do I need to apply my own interpolation function on a dataframe where I add a new row with 15 under the column pivot_column? or after grouping by the dataframe, apply np.interp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `concat` the new rows with the value of 15 in `pivot_column` and then `interpolate`:

```
other = pd.DataFrame({"input_date": df["input_date"].unique(), "pivot_column": 15})
df2 = pd.concat([df,other])
df3 = df2.groupby("input_date").apply(lambda g: g.set_index("pivot_column").interpolate("index")).drop(columns="input_date").reset_index()

#keep only required rows
output = other.merge(df3)

>>> output
   input_date  pivot_column    val1  val2
0  2023/11/02            15  3200.0  35.0
1  2023/11/03            15  3100.0  32.3
```